# how to do two type of search in adapter in android

Tags: android, android-listview, textwatcher

I am trying to implement quick search in listview having custom adapter.The problem here is i am having two edit text through which i am entering the filter value,but using only one adapter,so by default its taking the first edit text value but not the second one.For one edit text the functionality working fine.
Below is the code for the two edit text

```
edtsearchorder.addTextChangedListener(this);

edtsearchtable.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

here the edtsearchorder and edtsearchtable is the two edit text from where i am entering the filter value.

below is the part for edit text search.

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(originaldatalist.size()!=0)
        {
            hidevirtualkeyboardinfragment();
            dineorderadapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);

        }


    }
```

all the unimplemented method of TextWatcher interface.

So is there any way to perform search operation while using two edit text.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
edtsearchorder.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

     }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(originaldatalist.size()!=0)
        {
           hidevirtualkeyboardinfragment();
           dineorderadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
     }
});

edtsearchtable.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

     }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         if(originaldatalist.size()!=0)
         {
            hidevirtualkeyboardinfragment();
            dineorderadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: There is a conflict because if the edtsearchorder value and the edtsearchtable value is same non filter is happening for e.g. if the edtsearchorder is 1 and edtsearchtable is 1,so as you know we have do filter in adapter according to some specific item like student roll or student name.If any other way is there